# Python: splitting DataFrame based on numerical sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

I'm searching for a Pythonic implementation of splitting a pandas DataFrame based on multiple pre-defined numerical sequences in one column (in this example, `state`).

**Example:**

```
sequence_1 = [4, 1, 5, 2]
sequence_2 = [3, 0]
test_data = pd.DataFrame({'state': [4, 1, 5, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0],
                      'output': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]})
```

**Desired output:**
Split into

```
0 4 1
1 1 1
2 5 0
3 2 1

4 4 1
5 1 3
6 5 1
7 2 1

8 3 3
9 0 2
```

and so on.

As long as it preserves the index and other values, I'm not worried about the output format. I've had a bit of a look at `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, but haven't had any luck. I also tried `isin`, but it needs to match the specific sequence in order and with all values present.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that some rows won't be in any split you are looking for? in your example it would be a row with a state of 6 or one with 4 but followed by 0 instead of 1 (such as the order is not like in your sequence lists). Second question: can the sequences have a value in commum?

Comment: For your first question: it is possible, but only at the start or end of the df (sequences being cut off early - the ideal behaviour in this case would be to just ignore and drop them). There won't be any states outside of 0-5.

Comment: For your second question: no common values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An fast way if your data in `state` is well ordered like in your example would be to catch only the first element of both sequences and then `cumsum` in a `groupby` such as:

```
for name_g, df_g in test_data.groupby(((test_data.state == sequence_1[0])| 
                                       (test_data.state == sequence_2[0]) ).cumsum()):
    print (df_g)
```

One more general way could be to use `shift` to check if the sequence is in the right order and then get the dataframes in a `list` for example:

```
ser_seq1 = np.array([test_data.state.shift(-i) == val 
                     for i, val in enumerate(sequence_1)]).all(0)
list_df_seq1 = [test_data.loc[i:i+len(sequence_1)] 
                for i in test_data.index[ser_seq1]]
```

and same with `sequence_2`

Comment: Thank you! Your first solution was exactly what I was after.